# bubble.io DB and Java library integration

Tags: java, bubble.io

I would like to know if there is a Java library to connect to bubble.io (Bubble is the most powerful no-code platform for creating digital products) Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no dedicated libraries/SDKs to interface with Bubble database - you can use your favorite HTTP request library in Java (such as `HttpClient`) to connect to Bubble's Data API following directions [here](https://manual.bubble.io/core-resources/api/data-api).